# plot vertical line with DO

Tags: printing, wolfram-mathematica

i try to plot the result of this code as vertical line each one in the position of the solution of the FindRoot routine (something like that: http://www.astrobio.net/albums/xsolar/ach.sized.jpg ).

```
    omega[a_] := 2 \[Pi] /a^(3/2);
Do[
Print[FindRoot[omega[a]/omega[5.2]==j/i+1, {a, 1}]],
{j,1,7,1},{i,1,7,1}]
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: But ... what goes into each axis?

Comment: i must plot a dataset and add lines of same width in the plot. Like the link i posted in the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm part guessing, because your question isn't clear enough:

```
omega[a_] := 2 Pi/a^(3/2);
ListPlot[Flatten[
  Table[{a /. FindRoot[omega[a]/omega[5.2] == j/i + 1, {a, 1}], i + j}, 
              {j, 1, 7, 1}, {i, 1, 7, 1}], 1], 
 Filling -> Axis,  PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 15}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: i must plot a dataset and add lines of same width in the plot. Like the link i posted in the description. Like the plot of @belisarius but all point at the same level, for example y=8. THANKSSS :D

Comment: i find the solution: change i+j whit a costant value for example 8.

Comment: @federico Next time write down the full specification :) Suerte!